# Hiding the name of the user who is currently editing

Tags: posts

I am creating a website. I need to hide the avatar and the name of the user who is currently editing, and replace the name with the role. Is that possible?

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The avatar and text is set in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php. It's not directly filterable, but it's possible to use JavaScript to target them and change since they each have their own class names.

For avatars, target `.locked-avatar`, the text is inside `.locked-text`.

The text itself is translatable on the PHP side, so it's possible to filter `gettext` calls to change the string before it's displayed, but that will only get the text, not the user's name or avatar, so I suggest going with CSS/JS on the front end first.

Answer (score 0):

The editing user is determined by `wp_check_post_lock()`, which in turn checks the `_edit_lock` postmeta field:

```
function wp_check_post_lock( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! $lock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_edit_lock', true ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $lock = explode( ':', $lock );
    $time = $lock[0];
    $user = isset( $lock[1] ) ? $lock[1] : get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_edit_last', true );

    if ( ! get_userdata( $user ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php */
    $time_window = apply_filters( 'wp_check_post_lock_window', 150 );

    if ( $time && $time > time() - $time_window && $user != get_current_user_id() ) {
        return $user;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You could carefully setup a filter on `get_post_metadata` and return another user id (the field contains a string made up of a timestamp and the user id separated by a colon, e.g. `123456789:1`), for example the user id of a custom user with the username "Anonymous".

You might have to put some measures in place to only overwrite it on the overview, so your users don't get surprised by "somebody else is editing this post" alerts when they are entering edit mode (I'm not sure it would happen, but it might), but other than that, I don't think there should be any nasty side effects. Be sure to test it thoroughly before deploying it.